# using if else with switch

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    char ans, cont;
    ans = 'y';

    while (true){
        if (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y'){
            cout << "Enter a price:" << endl;
            cin >> n;
            n++;

            cout << "do you want to continue? y/n" <<endl;
            cin >> ans;

            switch (n) {
                //Vat Prices
                case 1:
                    if (n<300)
                        cout << "You have to pay" << endl << n *  1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if (n==300)
                        cout << "You have to pay" << endl << (n * 1.05) * 1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    if (n>=301 && n <= 500)
                        cout << "You have to pay" << endl << (n * 1.1) * 1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
                    break;

                case 4:
                    if (n>= 501 && n <= 1000)
                        cout << "You have to pay" << endl << (n * 1.2)*1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;

                case 5:
                    if (n>1000)
                        cout << "You have to pay" << endl << (n * 1.3)* 1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If i put `n` the program wont go through the switch, it worked fine an hour ago, I  don't know what happened

Comment: Did you mean to use `ans` instead of `n`? ... because it is quite obvious that, e.g., `n > 1000` will never hold if `n == 5` (for the last case).

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation isn't helping you any, either.  That switch statement isn't doing what you might think it is.  When you do something like this:

```
switch (n) {
case 1:
   //do stuff
   break;
case 2:
   //do stuff
   break
default:
   //do stuff
}
```

The 1 and 2 in the cases above are the values of n that you're switching on, i.e. when `n == 1`, it'll do the first case; when `n == 2` it'll do the second case; otherwise it'll do the default block.

Following the cases with `if` statements accomplishes nothing that the switch didn't already do for you.  1 works because when `n == 1` the conditional `n < 300` is automatically true.  But all of your other cases rely on n being 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, and as a result, none of those other tests can possible pass.

What you really want is:

```
if (n < 300) {
    // do stuff
} else if (n == 300) {
    // do stuff
} else if (n > 300) {
    // do stuff
} etc...
```

Comment: I fixed the indentation in an edit. Someone just needs to review it.

Comment: +1 for explaining what I was too lazy to say explicitly. Nice answer. Given the novice nature of the question, it might be prudent to clarify what you mean by "the values of n that you're switching on."

Answer (score 1):

This is not how switch works. Since you're making decisions based on ranges, you'll want just a plain if/else if/else chain. For more information on how to use a switch read [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to put
    cout << "do you want to continue? y/n" <> ans;

at the end of your `while` loop.

Furthermore, I'd also suggest just having it say

```
while (ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
```

However the big problem is that your `switch` statement only works if n==1. Get rid of the whole `switch` statement and just use the `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

Your `switch` statement will only hit a case if the price entered is `1, 2, 3, 4 or 5`. Switches don't work how you're trying to use them, and you're better off using an `if-else` control structure.

```
if(n<300)
  cout << "You have to pay" << endl << n *  1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
else if(n==300)
  cout << "You have to pay" << endl << (n * 1.05) * 1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
else if(n <= 500)
  cout << "You have to pay" << endl << (n * 1.1) * 1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
else if (<= 1000)
  cout << "You have to pay" << endl << (n * 1.2)*1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
else
  cout << "You have to pay" << endl << (n * 1.3)* 1.1 << "  $" << endl <<endl;
```

Furthermore, you are just overwriting your `n` variable each time you loop. You then increment it by 1, `n++`. This doesn't make much sense.